# Making two model from one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building doctor-appointment site. I have User model and I want to divide it into two parts: physician and patient. I have tried:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :physician, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :patient, class_name: "User"     
   end

class Physician < User
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments, source: "User"
end

class Patient < User
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments, source: "User"
end
```

PROBLEM: how to get physician_id and patient_id column in appointsments table?
I've chosen this way, because when Physician and Patient models are separated, the registration will be problem (I think so...).

Comment: Also you might want to look at single table inheritance or STI as it appears that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path and only need to run a migration to add references to physician and patient on appointments table.
Although, you wouldn't need to add the source attribute to either the patients or physician has_many through anymore as those would be inferred by Rails!

I think I also prefer this approach of having the Physician and the Patient model, although not for registration purposes, but for single responsibility!

Let me know if that works

Comment: You can find more details about the `inverse_of` option [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations). Basically, the places I've really seen the use is when saving associated records, e.g if you were trying to create a child record for a parent that has not been persisted, you'd get an error that the parent hasn't been saved, however using the inverse_of option, you'd be able to save this record. You should remove the `source` option in both the Physician and Patient model, though as it appears redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
add_reference :appointments, :patient, foreign_key: true
add_reference :appointments, :physician, :foreign_key: true
```

These two migrations should add foreign keys to your table. Check the docs to make sure my syntax is absolutely correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes `dpalazzari` suggested I believe you will want to make the following changes:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician, class_name: "Physician", inverse_of: :appointments
  belongs_to :patient,   class_name: "Patient",   inverse_of: :appointments     
end

class Physician < User
  has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :physician_id, inverse_of: :physician
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments, source: "User"
end

class Patient < User
  has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :patient_id, inverse_of: :patient
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments, source: "User"
end
```